# Remove sequentially duplicate frames when using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, duplicates

Is there any way to detect duplicate frames within the video using `ffmpeg`?

I tried `-vf` flag with `select=gt(scene\,0.xxx)` for scene change. But, it did not work for my case.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use the [mpdecimate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mpdecimate) filter, whose purpose is to "Drop frames that do not differ greatly from the previous frame in order to reduce frame rate."

- This will generate a console readout showing which frames the filter thinks are duplicates.

  ```
   ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf mpdecimate -loglevel debug -f null -
  ```
- To generate a video from a video source with audio with the duplicates removed

  ```
   ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf mpdecimate -vsync vfr out.mp4
  ```
- To generate a video from a video source without audio with the duplicates removed

  ```
   ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mp4
  ```

---

The [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts) filter expression generates smooth timestamps for a video at `FRAME_RATE` FPS. See an explanation for timestamps at [What is video timescale, timebase, or timestamp in ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43337235/2587343)

Comment: that's what i'm looking for. thanx!

Comment: Me too! Thank you very much!

Comment: I did that, and it worked great, thanks.   As a bonus, the mp4 file was significantly less megabytes, even though it only scraped out a couple frames.

Comment: Is the `FRAME_RATE` to be substituded with the frame rate?

Comment: @MarkNeu No, it references the FPS detected by ffmpeg

Comment: `setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB` give me a completely out of sync file with erratic video behavior (compare Vlastimil Ovčáčík's answer).

Comment: @Suuuehgi  It is meant for video-only files. With audio, skip the setpts filter and add `-vsync vfr`

Comment: @Gyan: Using the FFMPEG command you suggested
`ffmpeg -i OriginalVideo.mp4 -y -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 output.mp4`
, followed by auto green screen from [runwayml.com] and Adobe After Effects (to regenerate missing frames) I was able to convert this stuttering video [ https://youtube.com/shorts/phNGmjLkjT0 ] into this result [ https://youtu.be/lSLYfehLtgM?si=w7Z0wtleTJvsh6c2&t=117 ]
(left side is the original)

Answer (score 50):

I also had this problem and Gyan's excellent answer above got me started but the result of it was desynchronized audio so I had to explore more options:

#### [mpdecimate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mpdecimate) vs [decimate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#decimate-1) filters

- `mpdecimate` is the standard recommendation I found all over SO and the internet, but I don't think it should be the first pick

  - it uses heuristics so it may and will skip some duplicate frames
  - you can tweak the detection with `frac` parameter, but that's extra work you may want to avoid if you can
  - it is not really supposed to work [with `mp4` container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089629/2587343) ([source](http://www.ffmpeg-archive.org/Re-mpdecimate-and-setpts-td4682831.html)), but I was using `mkv` so this limitation didn't apply on my case, but good to be aware of it
- `decimate` removes frames precisely, but it is useful only for periodically occurring duplicates

#### detected vs actual frame rate

- so you have multimedia file with duplicate frames, it is good idea to make sure that the detected frame rate matches the actual one
- `ffprobe in.mkv` will output the detected FPS; it may look like this

  `Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)`
- the actual frame rate can be found out if you open the media `in.mkv` in a media player that lets you step one frame at the time; then count the steps needed to advance the playback time for 1 second, in my case it was **30 fps**
- *not a big surprise for me, because every 6th frame was duplicate (5 good frames and 1 duplicate), so after 25 good frames there was also 5 duplicates*

#### what is `N/FRAME_RATE/TB`

- except the use of `FRAME_RATE` variable the `N/FRAME_RATE/TB` is equal to the example below from ffmpeg documentation ([source](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-123))

  > Set fixed rate of 25 frames per second:
  >   `setpts=N/(25*TB)`
- the math behind it perfectly explained in [What is video timescale, timebase, or timestamp in ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43337235/2587343)

  - it basically calculates timestamp for each frame and multiplies it with timebase `TB` to enhance precision

#### `FRAME_RATE` variable vs literal FPS value (e.g. 25)

- this is why it is important to know your detected and actual FPS
- if the detected FPS matches your actual FPS (e.g. both are **30 fps**) you can happily use `FRAME_RATE` variable in `N/FRAME_RATE/TB`
- but if the detected FPS differs than you have to calculate the `FRAME_RATE` on your own

  - in my case my actual FPS was **30** frames per second and I removed every 6th frame, so the target FPS is **25** which leads to `N/25/TB`

    - if I used `FRAME_RATE` (and I actually tried that) it would take the wrong detected fps of **25** frames i.e. `FRAME_RATE=25`, run it through `mpdecimate` filter which would remove every 6th frame and it would update to `FRAME_RATE=20.833` so `N/FRAME_RATE/TB` would actually be `N/20.833/TB` **which is completely wrong**

#### to use or not to use [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts)

- so the [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts) filter already got pretty complicated especially because of the FPS mess that duplicate frames may create
- the good news is you actually may not need the [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts) filter at all
- here is what I used with **good results**

  `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf mpdecimate out.mkv`

  `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf decimate=cycle=6,setpts=N/25/TB out.mkv`
- but the following gave me **desynchronized audio**

  `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mkv`

  `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/25/TB out.mkv`

  `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf decimate=cycle=6 out.mkv`
- as you see

  - [mpdecimate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mpdecimate) and [decimate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#decimate-1) does not work the same way
  - [mpdecimate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mpdecimate) worked better for me without [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts) filter
  - while [decimate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#decimate-1) needed [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts) filter and furthermore I need to avoid `FRAME_RATE` variable and use `N/25/TB` instead because the actual FPS was not detected properly

#### note on [asetpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts)

- it does the same job as [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts) does but for audio
- it didn't really fix desync audio for me but you want to use it something like this `-af asetpts=N/SAMPLE_RATE/TB`
- maybe you are supposed to adjust the `SAMPLE_RATE` according to the ratio of duplicate frames removed, but it seems to me like extra unnecessary work especially when my video  had the audio in sync at the beginning, so it is better to use commands that will keep it that way instead of fixing it later

---

#### tl;dr

If the usually recommended command `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mkv` does not work for you try this:

`ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf mpdecimate out.mkv`

or

`ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf decimate=cycle=6,setpts=N/25/TB out.mkv`

*(`cycle=6` because every 6th frame is duplicate and `N/25/TB` because after removing the duplicates the video will have 25 fps (avoid the `FRAME_RATE` variable); adjust for your use case)*

Comment: The setpts is needed with mp4 because it is a constant frame rate muxer. Add `-vsync vfr` and remove setpts in my command to keep deduplicated frames with same timestamp when saving to mp4

Comment: `Add -vsync vfr and remove setpts in my command` @Gyan --- Well that's exactly what I did for the usecase with `mpdecimate`, specifically I removed the `setpts` filter and I didn't even needed the `-vsync vfr`. It's all in `tl;dr` section.

Comment: `The setpts is needed with mp4 because it is a constant frame rate muxer` @Gyan --- that's interesting, but also notice that while I was able to remove `setpts` filter from the `mpdecimate` filter usecase (as you suggest), I **had to** use `setpts` for the `decimate` usecase. Both are `mkv`. Go figure right?!

Comment: When trying `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf [mpdecimate][] out.mkv` I get `[AVFilterGraph @ ...] Bad (empty?) label found in the following: "[]".`
`Error reinitializing filters!`
`Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument.`
`Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0` as error.

Comment: Hi @Tijmen and thanks for pointing out the problem! I have investigated a bit and it seems there was an [edit to the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52062421/2) that has broken the ffmpeg commands. As I see from your comment, you have used the broken commands. To be specific, the command you used `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf [mpdecimate][] out.mkv` is defective and the correct one is `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf mpdecimate out.mkv` (notice there are no  square brackets). It is all fixed now.

Comment: Just tried this solution on a 4 hour video, and the video was still 4 hours afterwards.
I expected this solution to totally cut out the repeated frames, but it looks like it only compressed them?

If I wanted a shorter video, by removing duplicate frames, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @XavierHorn: You can try the repo  [mpdecimate_trim](https://github.com/KenjiTakahashi/mpdecimate_trim). I explained how in a new response.

Comment: The `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mkv` which this answer says is wrong seems to do what @Xavier Horn and I and were expecting.

Comment: Furthermore `decimate` also uses heuristics and only drops 1 out of every N frames whereas `mpdecimate` will drop a whole sequence of frames in a row, so I don't know where the claim that `mpdecimate` will miss more duplicates than `decimate` came from.  It seems the other way around to me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solution here and none of them seem to work when you need to trim the video and keep the audio. There is a [mpdecimate_trim](https://github.com/KenjiTakahashi/mpdecimate_trim) repo that does a good job. It basically list all the frames to be dropped (using `mpdecimate`) and then creates a complex filter to trim all those frames (and the corresponding audio) from the video by splitting the video and only including the portion without duplicate frames.

I did have to tweak a few options in the code though. For instance, in `mpdecimate_trim.py`, I had to change this line:

`dframes2 = get_dframes(ffmpeg(True, "-vf", "mpdecimate=hi=576", "-loglevel", "debug", "-f", "null", "-").stderr)`

I had to detect duplicates a bit more aggressively, so I changed the `mpdecimate` option to `mpdecimate=hi=64*32:lo=64*24:frac=0.05`

Answer (score 0):

If your getting duplicate frozen frames after cropping you could be entering your cmd line incorrectly.  I was entering the orders of parameters incorrectly causing the first few seconds of my video to freeze.  Here is the fix if that is the case. Hopefully this helps you avoid getting frozen frames altogether.

```
ffmpeg -ss {start_time} -i {input_path} -vcodec copy -acodec copy -to {end_time} {output_path}
```