# How to "de-duplicate" video frames in a video, keeping the audio in sync?

Tags: video, video-processing, video-encoding

I have a bunch of low motion & high framerate videos (i.e. desktop recordings) and want to remove frames that are an exact duplicate of the previous frame, without messing up the video speed and audio. The videos are mostly encoded in H.264 and are visually lossless.

Comment: Use FFMPEG and follow this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088517/ffmpeg-remove-sequentially-duplicate-frames)

Answer (score 0):

I would try Avisynth.
This would do it: http://avisynth.nl/index.php/External_filters#Duplicate_Frame_Detectors
Y