# Using ffmpeg to remove duplicate frames and connected audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg, I was able to remove duplicate frames from a video using `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mp4`. However, the audio went on for longer than the video, obviously because the command only removed the video portion. How would I remove the segments of audio which accompany the removed frames?

Comment: I got to the bottom of this problem in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062421/2587343)