# ffmpeg: drop duplicate frames and the audio within each frame

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I used ffmpeg to drop duplicated video frames using `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mp4`, but I want to also drop the audio between the frames. How can I do this?

Comment: What's the difference between this question and your other one? [Using ffmpeg to remove duplicate frames and connected audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189010/using-ffmpeg-to-remove-duplicate-frames-and-connected-audio)

Comment: This question is aimed at using the above command and removing the audio simultaneously, while the other is more specific to frame by frame procedure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ffmpeg to remove duplicate frames and connected audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189010/using-ffmpeg-to-remove-duplicate-frames-and-connected-audio)