# ffmpeg - remove duplicate frames block (same video sequence twice)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transport-stream

Any idea how to remove duplicate video&audio frames blocks (several seconds repeating video sequences having same timestamps and frames ~ corrupt file) from TS file with ffmpeg?

I tried:

1) [decimate filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089629/6341080):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mp4
```

- does reencoding
- does not remove several seconds repeated frames block

2) playing with synchronisation options

```
ffmpeg -vsync vfr -frame_drop_threshold 1500 -i in.ts -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y out.ts
```

- there is no help with frame_drop_threshold attribude, no sample usage found on internet
- does not reencode input
- does not remove several seconds repeated frames block

Seems ffmpeg helps:

- just with sequence of same frames
- not with repeating frames sequences in the stream
- not with removing (dropping) frames with repeated timestamps

Comment: Does the video decode fine - any playback corruption?

Comment: There is no issue in vlc player, I just need to remove repeating sequences (lasting several seconds).

Comment: Then my suggestion is to segment the movie at keyframes. Delete neighbouring segments of equal bytesize or frame count and rejoin the remainder. See the [segment](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) muxer for segmenting and [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1) demuxer for joining.