# Reporting duplicated frames with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am looking for a method to report (not just detect and remove) duplicated frames of video detected by FFmpeg  - similar to how you can print out blackdetect, cropdetect, silencedetect, etc.

For example:

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf blackdetect -an -f null - 2>&1 | grep blackdetect > output.txt

Outputs something like:

[blackdetect @ 0x7f8032f03680] black_start:5.00501 black_end:7.00701 black_duration:2.002

But there's no "dupedetect" filter as far as I know, so I'm looking for any ideas/workarounds to get a read of where frames are duplicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ffmpeg - remove sequentially duplicate frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088517/ffmpeg-remove-sequentially-duplicate-frames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `-vp mpdecimate` in the command line.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf mpdecimate -loglevel debug -an -f null - 2>&1 | grep 'drop_count:\d' > output.txt
```

Sample line of output:

```
[Parsed_mpdecimate_0 @ 0x7fbbfa210380] lo:0<2653 lo:0<1326 lo:0<1326 drop pts:101101 pts_time:4.21254 drop_count:1
```

Comment: Thanks - though it seems the decimate and fieldmatch video filters don't seem to print out where it's detecting the duplicates, just removes them on an output video.

Comment: Try setting `-loglevel debug` and removing the `grep`.

Comment: Thank you so much - I forgot about debug level. Here's what that outputs:
https://pastebin.com/Rr12Sn1Y

In the test I used, it had third frame repeats randomly throughout, and you can see where the filter dropped frames in debug. I think this will work!

Comment: @Calculon Note that this is fuzzy matching; you'll need to set the high and low filter options accordingly if you want it to be exact matching.

Comment: Yeah, even standard has worked pretty well for my purposes already, but I may tweak it. I am getting mixed files with random dupe frames I need to report and this is definitely finding them.