# Extracting number of duplicate (or dropped) frames in ffmpeg via C API

Tags: c, ffmpeg

Is there a way to extract number of duplicated or dropped video frames during the decoding of a .mp4 or .ts file through ffmpeg's C API?

This information is reported by ffmpeg [when using the command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51273508/5223757).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not applicable.

Dup/drop with the CLI is carried out by the ffmpeg program, specifically the vsync/fps_mode code. This is not exposed or used by any of the libav* API calls.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way to set fps_mode via C API? or is it only a CLI option?

Comment: Only a CLI option. Basic idea is to check interval with previous frame and clone/drop frame if interval is more/less than 1/framerate.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.